# Connecting a 12v router to a 12v battery

Tags: batteries, router

can I connect a 12v router directly to a 12v battery which normally will be at 13-14v (because most of the time it’ll be charging)?
The router is a TP LINK Archer MR200 rated at 12V 1A

Comment: Use a DC to DC converter and, of course, a fuse.

Comment: It's probable that connecting your battery directly to the router will be just fine. The router will work over a range of voltage even though they have not specified that range in the literature. However, it depends on the regulator built into the router just how high or low you could go. You'd be best to ask a question on the TP-Link forum or via Tech support as I'm sure this problem has been dealt with by them before. A DC-DC converter could solve the problem, but you'd potentially need a Boost/Buck version to cover the full range of battery voltages (say 11 - 14V),

Comment: There are plenty of Buck/Boost DC-DC convertors available, if you search for regulators based on the XL6009 in your favorite store  you will find examples such as this: https://www.ebay.com/itm/DC-DC-Boost-Buck-adjustable-step-up-down-Converter-XL6009-Module-Solar-Voltage/201544467794

Comment: it should be fine (connecting directly and right way around) but tp-link company will never inform you about that